# Compactness of the outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, compactness

I have maybe a naive question about compactness of outer measure (or completion).

Let $(E,\mathcal B(E))$ be a Polish space, and $\mathcal M_b(E)$ the bounded Radon measure on $E$.  Assume that a sequence $\{\mu_n\}$ weakly converge to $\mu$ in $\mathcal M_b(E)$ i.e.
$$ \int_E \varphi \mu_n \to \int_E \varphi \mu  \,, \quad \forall \varphi\in \mathcal C_b(E,\mathbb R)$$
where integration (and continuity) is made throuth the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(E)$.

Is it true that the same holds for the completion of $\mu_n$? Namely, let $\mu_n^*$ the (unique) completion of $\mu_n$ for all $n$, do we have
$$ \int_E \varphi \mu_n^* \to \int_E \varphi \mu^*  \,,\quad \forall \varphi\in \mathcal C_b(E,\mathbb R)$$ 
where integration (and continuity) is made throuth the extended $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu^*$ the (unique) completion of $\mu$.

I do not realize if it is trivial or not... Maybe some hints?

Comment: But you are integrating the same functions $\varphi$ (that are measurable) and you know that $\int_E\varphi\,d\mu=\int_E\varphi\,d\mu^*$. Doesn't this imply that you have the same convergence?

Comment: ??? If $\mu$ is a Radon measure and $\phi$ is continuous then $\int\phi\,d\mu=\int\phi\,d\mu^*$. The only difference between $\int f\,d\mu$ and $\int f\,d\mu^*$ is that it's possible for $f$ to be measurable on the completed $\sigma$-algebra but not on the original. Since $\phi$ is continuous it's measurable on the original.

Comment: Yep, ok it was a bit stupid my question :)